# Django Bootstrap Modal Form Not Rendering

Tags: python, django, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to create a simple popup with Django Bootstrap Modal. I can't get the form to render on screen. I've been following the official [Documentation](https://pypi.org/project/django-bootstrap-modal-forms/) with no luck. I would like to be able to activate the popup from a reference link on my base.html. How do I make this modal form popup when a link is clicked from my base.html?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Views:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from bootstrap_modal_forms.generic import BSModalCreateView
from .forms import CustomUserCreationForm

class SignUpView(BSModalCreateView):
    form_class = CustomUserCreationForm
    template_name = 'blog/signup.html'
    success_message = 'Success: Sign up succeeded. You can now Log in.'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('index')

posts = [
    {
        'author': 'ShanePa',
        'title': 'Blog Post',
        'content': 'First post conent',
        'date_posted': 'August 27, 2018'

    },
    {
        'author': 'ColePa',
        'title': 'Blog Post 2',
        'content': 'Second post conent',
        'date_posted': 'August 28, 2018'
    }
]

artists = [

    {
        'artist': 'Cole',
        'pic1': 'Blog Post',
        'pic2': 'First post conent',
        'pic3': 'August 27, 2018',
        'pic4': 'August 27, 2018'

    },

    {   

        'artist': 'Mikey',
        'pic1': 'Blog Post',
        'pic2': 'First post conent',
        'pic3': 'August 27, 2018',
        'pic4': 'August 27, 2018'
    },

    {   

        'artist': 'Josh',
        'pic1': 'Blog Post',
        'pic2': 'First post conent',
        'pic3': 'August 27, 2018',
        'pic4': 'August 27, 2018'

    },

    {   

        'artist': 'Matt',
        'pic1': 'Blog Post',
        'pic2': 'First post conent',
        'pic3': 'August 27, 2018',
        'pic4': 'August 27, 2018'
    }

]

def home(request):
    '''
    context = {
        'posts': posts  
    }
    '''

    context = {
        'artists': artists
    }

    return render(request, 'blog/home.html', context)


def news(request):
    return render(request, 'blog/news.html', {'title': 'About'})

def shows(request):
    return render(request, 'blog/shows.html', {'title': 'About'})

def sustainability(request):
    return render(request, 'blog/sustainability.html', {'title': 'About'})
```

URLS:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name = 'social-home'),
    path('news/', views.news, name = 'social-news'),
    path('shows/', views.shows, name = 'social-shows'),
    path('sustainability/', views.sustainability, name = 'social-sustainability'),
    path('signup/', views.SignUpView.as_view(), name='signup')

]
```

Base.html

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <script src= '/static/blog/apps.js'></script>

     <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/blog/main.css?'{% now 'U' %}"/>

    {% if title %}
        <title>The Social - {{ title }}</title>
    {% else %}
        <title>The Social</title>
    {% endif %}

</head>

<body onload="overlay()">

    <div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="modal">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <button class="signup-btn btn btn-primary" type="button" name="button"  data-target=>Sign up</button>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function () {
        // Sign up button
        $(".signup-btn").modalForm({formURL: "{% url 'signup' %}"});

      });
    </script>

    <header class="site-header">
        <div class="container">
          <a class="center-title" href="{% url 'social-home' %}">The Social</a>
            <!-- Navbar Right Side -->
            <div class="navbar-nav">
              <a class="nav-item-login" href="#">Login In</a>
              <a class="nav-item-register" href="#">Sign Up</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </header>

    <div class="container">
         {% block content %}{% endblock %}
    </div>

    <div class="navbar2">
      <a href="{% url 'social-news' %}" class="active">NEWS</a>
      <a href="{% url 'social-home' %}" class ="active">ARTISTS</a>
      <a href="{% url 'social-shows' %}" class ="active">SHOWS</a>
      <a href="{% url 'social-sustainability' %}" class="active">SUSTAINABILITY</a>
    </div>

    <footer class="navbar3">
        <a href="#Contact" onclick='overlay()' class="active">CONTACT</a>
        <a href="#About" class="active">ABOUT</a>
    </footer>

    <div id ="overlay">
        <div>
            <p>Content you want will go here</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <a href='#' onclick='overlay()'>Click here to show the overlay</a>

    Click here to [<a href='#' onclick='overlay()'>close</a>]

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.bootstrap.modal.forms.js' %}"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

signup.html:

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}

{% load widget_tweaks %}

<form method="post" action="">
  {% csrf_token %}

  <div class="modal-header">
    <h3 class="modal-title">Sign up</h3>
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>

  <div class="modal-body">

    <div class="{% if form.non_field_errors %}invalid{% endif %} mb-2">
      {% for error in form.non_field_errors %}
        {{ error }}
      {% endfor %}
    </div>

    {% for field in form %}
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="{{ field.id_for_label }}">{{ field.label }}</label>
        {% render_field field class="form-control" placeholder=field.label %}
        <div class="{% if field.errors %} invalid{% endif %}">
          {% for error in field.errors %}
            <p class="help-block">{{ error }}</p>
          {% endfor %}
        </div>
      </div>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>

  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="submit-btn btn btn-primary">Sign up</button>
  </div>

</form>
```

forms.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from bootstrap_modal_forms.mixins import PopRequestMixin, CreateUpdateAjaxMixin


class CustomUserCreationForm(PopRequestMixin, CreateUpdateAjaxMixin,
                             UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'password1', 'password2']
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems that you've forgotten to enclose your actual form between **{% block content %}** *your form* **{% endblock content%}**, so that it can be displayed in the intended place in base.html. [See template inheritance.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/language/#template-inheritance)

In your 'base.html' file you have defined a {% block content %}{% endblock content %} to inject content. But the injected content has to have a **{% block content %}** *your code here* **{% endblock content %}** so that it "knows" what to fuse/inject.

But keep in mind that the way you've implemented it, it's while navigating to signup.html that the form will actually be displayed.

Another way to inject content inside, let's say *target.html* from *source.html*, is to use **{% include 'source.html' %}** inside target.html at the desired section.
Whitout adding any other tags inside source.html
[See {% include %} tag.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#include)